# jackson json JsonIgnoreProperties and DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES do not work for non string fields

Tags: jackson

I have a Map fields in json file
"companyAddress" : {
"street1" : "99 test Ct",
"postalCode" : "95050",
"city" : "Santa Clara",
"state" : "CA",
"country" : "USA"
}

If my object does not have this field it throws `` com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException","error.message":"Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT ``

I tried `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` class level annotation
as well as `mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);`

The ignore field works only for String fields.
In fact for String fields no setting is required they are ignored if not present in class.

I am using jackson 2

Comment: You need to deserialize that JSON into a Java object `CompanyAddress` with another object that has the String fields on it, not directly to a String. The error is caused by Jackson encountering the first `{` when it is expecting a plain String value. Another option would be to only pass the object value of `companyAddress` to your Java code instead of the whole key/value pair.

Comment: The problem is we have an old object which does not have this field in the class.
how to have jackson ignore fields in json which are not in the class

Comment: The annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` should be working. From what I see based on that error is that you are trying to deserialize an object into a String. Could you post your full code where you actually attempt the deserialization?